# Silver Light : How to set unit as constant in a textbox

Tags: xaml, silverlight

I want to display some value in a TextBox in Silverlight, but I need to set a unit value that remains constant.

Example:

`100 gpm`

I need to change the value (`100`), but the unit (`gpm`) should always stay static.

Here is my current Binding.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Current.SystemDemand,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Are you using binding or setting the value directly

Comment: Binding from code behind..  Text="{Binding Path=Current.SystemDemand,Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: we need to add GotFocus and LostFocus events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Binding on the TextBox You can set the Format of the Binding.

Here is how you set the format in **Xaml**

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=Current.SystemDemand, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='\{0} gpm'}" />
```

Comment: Sorry , when I put this Text="{Binding Path=CurrentScenario.SystemDemand,Mode=TwoWay,StringFormat='{0} gpm'}" I got the error **Expected '''**

Comment: Slight typo. either put a space before the ` {0} gpm` or use backslash `\{0} gpm`. The designer complains when you start with a `{`

Comment: Sorry when I put StringFormat='/{0} gpm' , I got the output as  **/12.8 gpm**, A leading slash is getting

Comment: I told you the wrong slash. sorry. I've updated the answer with the correct slash

Comment: yes , you are right..It done the trick, But still **gpm** is editable , but I need only 12.8 is editable, anyway this is working.But I need little bit more..

Comment: whenever user enters a value in the Textbox  , it should append **gpm**

Comment: It should append `gpm` using the string format. that happens when the text box loses focus

Comment: sorry, gpm is not appending when textbox loses the focus

Comment: we need to add **GotFocus** and **LostFocus** events

Answer (score 1):

What the question author's approach and the accepted answer have in common is that they mix up the (editable) value and the (non-editable) unit.

Why not place an ordinary `TextBlock` containing the unit near the end of your `TextBox`?

You can even use a `Grid` to have the unit appear "inside" the `TextBox`.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding...StringToNumberConverter...etc}" Padding="0,0,24,0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="gpm" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="false"/>
</Grid>
```